# how to prevent vba to convert the value type while copy and pasting?

Tags: excel, vba

> Blockquote

hello i am trying to copy and paste a text formatted column's values from sheet1 to sheet 2. However the value type automatically changed into number.

Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim src As Worksheet
    Dim tgt As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Variant

```
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set src = wb.Sheets("sheet1")
Set tgt = wb.Sheets("sheet2")

lastRow = src.Range("A" & src.Rows.Count).End(xlDown).Row



tgt.Range("E43:E" & lastRow).Value = src.Range("A5:A" & lastRow).Value
```

> what i get with this code is

```
 1
 2
 11
 12
```

> the data is formatted in sheet1 like this:

```
 00000001
 00000002
 00000011
 00000012
```

> and i want the same thing in sheet 2

Comment: then on sheet2 just `tgt.Range("E43:E" & lastRow)..NumberFormat =  "0000000"`

Comment: hey thank you for your response. however I am getting a compiler error :/

Comment: simple - use `copy` see my answer below...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned, you need to reproduce the custom number format that forces the leading zeroes from the source.

You also need to reshape the target to the same size as the source. Using *lastRow* for both only works when they start with the same row (which your example does not).

```
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set src = wb.Sheets("sheet1")
Set tgt = wb.Sheets("sheet2")

with src

  lastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(XLUP).Row  '<~~ xlUp, not xlDown

  with .Range("A5:A" & lastRow)

    tgt.Range("E43").resize(.rows.count, .columns.count) = .Value2
    tgt.Range("E43").resize(.rows.count, .columns.count).numberformat = "00000000"

  end with

end with
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `.Value` and you will get desired results

Example:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B2") = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2")
```

Edit: Try the below additional line

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1") = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").NumberFormat = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").NumberFormat
```

Comment: Are you sure its text formatted and not number formatted?. Let me know if edited answer works.

Comment: in sheet1 when i put my arrow on the number it shows "the number in the cell is formatted as text or preceded by an apostrophe. But there is no apostrophe :/

Answer (score 0):

Use copy and it will copy the cell/s exactly

```
src.Range("A5:A" & lastRow).Copy tgt.Range("E43:E" & lastRow)
```